# Where is definition of Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V?

Tags: java, jvm

I am trying to implement JVM(Java8) by python as a study.

I want to execute `java Main`. In main method, Person instance will be initialized.
Then Person class constructor invoke special `Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V`.
But I can't find the definition of that method although I saw [JVM spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/index.html).

Main.java

```java
class Main{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Person p = new Person("Jeff", 17);
  }
}
```

Person.java

```java
public class Person {
  private String name;
  private int age;
  public Person(String name, int age){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
}
```

To compile, I used `javac -encoding UTF-8  -target 8 -source 8 *.java`.

`javap -v Main` shows below

```
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    descriptor: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
    flags: (0x0009) ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
    Code:
      stack=4, locals=2, args_size=1
         0: new           #7                  // class Person
         3: dup
         4: ldc           #9                  // String Chisato
         6: bipush        17
         8: invokespecial #11                 // Method Person."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
        11: astore_1
        12: return
```

`javap -v Person` shows below

```
  public Person(java.lang.String, int);
    descriptor: (Ljava/lang/String;I)V
    flags: (0x0001) ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=3, args_size=3
         0: aload_0
         1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
         4: aload_0
         5: aload_1
         6: putfield      #7                  // Field name:Ljava/lang/String;
         9: aload_0
        10: iload_2
        11: putfield      #13                 // Field age:I
        14: return
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se17/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.9.1

Answer (score 2):

That's JVM-ese efor a method reference. `<init>` means 'constructor'. `()V` means: A method that takes no arguments and returns `void` (as in, nothing).

In other words this tuple of strings:

`java/lang/Object` `<init>` `()V`

refers to the no-args constructor of `java.lang.Object` itself. Which definitely exists, it's part of all java distributions.

The reason it is called here is basic java reasons:

- **ALL** classes **MUST** have a constructor.
- **ALL** constructors **MUST** begin by invoking either another constructor in the same class, or one of the super constructors. (`this();` or `super();` in java).
- If you fail to write a constructor, java assumes you meant to write `public MyClass() {}`.
- If you fail to write a `this()` or `super()` on the first line, java assumes you meant to write `super();` and will act as if you did.

Thus, your `Person` class has a constructor, and it begins by invoking its parent class's no-args constructor.

Which is `java/lang/Object` `<init>` `()V`.

The only class that is supposed to break this rule is `java.lang.Object` itself which has no parent class and doesn't do this. With bytecode hackery you can make classes that break these rules, and a JVM will run that just fine if you really want to. But don't - code in the JVM ecosystem expects you to do these things.

Answer (score 1):

A look at the source code of `java.lang.Object` (e.g. http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/lang/Object.java) shows that there are no explicit constructors in the `Object` class. As such, `Object` has a default constructor.

As stated in [JLS 8.8.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9):

> If a class contains no constructor declarations, then a default constructor is implicitly declared. The form of the default constructor for a top level class, member class, or local class is as follows:
>
> - ...
> - If the class being declared is the primordial class Object, then the default constructor has an empty body.

So, `Object.<init>()` is simply a constructor with an empty body.

In more recent versions (e.g. [OpenJDK head](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Object.java#L44)), there is an explicit constructor, but, again, it has an empty body:

```
    @IntrinsicCandidate
    public Object() {}
```